# Adding an extra field and value to a django queryset's objects

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

Let the following Model:

```
class Books(models.Model):
    b_name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    b_page = models.IntegerField()
```

What I want is to add an extra field with different values based on the logged user and on an other model object in the views.

The other model looks like this, whose taken_on's values I want to attach with the model Books:

```
class BookTakerInfo(models.Model):
    user = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    book_taken = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    taken_on = models.CharField(max_length=25)
```

And then render it to the templates, so that I can use it like following:

```
{% for b in books_qs %}
    {{b.extra_field}}
{% endfor %}
```

May be in views like this:

```
qs = Books.objects.filter(...)
for q in qs:
    obj = BookTakerInfo.objects.filter(...).first()
    q.add("taken_on", obj.taken_on)
```

And because the values are different and depending on user and taken on date, so I can't use a model field for this task.

Comment: What is this random value actually? It depends on what "random value" you want to include in the final result.

Comment: i want to add a integer value from an another model's object by filtering the other model according to logged_user

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`annotate()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.annotate) and [`F`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions) for this purpose:

```
from django.db.models import F


qs = Books.objects.filter(...).annotate(related_value=F('related_object__value'))

# In the end, you can access the annotated value like this:
qs.first().related_value
```

This is how you can add related object's integer value, as you desire.

Comment: what is this related_object__value? Could you please explain this code??

Comment: and one more thing, It seems like the books.objects.filter(...).annotate() will put the same value to all the objects in the qs. But I want to give them different values.

Comment: @FightWithCode You said you wanted to include a related object's integer value as a result in your filtered books queryset. The `annotate()` method helps you include that. The `F()` statement itself wraps a selector. `F('related_object__value')` is selecting the current `book.related_object.value` (your desired integer value).

Comment: @FightWithCode Values are different for every single element in the queryset.

Comment: @FightWithCode If you still have difficulties understanding this, please add your model hierarchy in the question and specify which value especially you want to include in your books queryset.

Comment: I added it please have a look on it. Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195440/discussion-between-wencakisa-and-fightwithcode).